# Google Cloud Postgres connection in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, google-app-engine, config, google-cloud-sql

I've created a web application and I've decided that I want to deploy it onto Google cloud. So, I'm currently porting my code so that it runs. I've been following this page :

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-sql-postgres#configure-csql-instance

For setting up a connection to a CloudSQL postgres instance. However, I'm getting confused about the line that deals with the config file :

```
properties.load(
      getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/config.properties"))
```

I don't have this config file my default, and I can't find anywhere that tells me what this config file should be / what should be in it.

Could anyone help me out with setting this file up?

Thanks!

Comment: This is just a properties file to get some properties like `sqlUrl`. Use whatever you like

Comment: Ok, thanks. How would I find out what the URL should be for the database? Obviously when I was running it locally it was local host with a port

Comment: Presumably it gets injected by the environment somehow?

Comment: If you click through the example to github, you will find this file: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/flexible/postgres/src/main/resources/config.properties 
The documentation page doesn't seem to describe this very well (or at all)

Comment: Awesom, thanks for the link. So the URL to connect to the database is just sqlUrl? That seems weird

Comment: It's replaced in the pm file: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/7949498de58ad9cf74d28644e9b166f44ba38e1c/flexible/postgres/pom.xml#L93